# model attribute is undefined method for active record relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails app where a user creates a question (Question model accepts nested attributes for Answer model) and at least three answer choices. The attributes on the Answer model are :content (for the question) and :correctanswer, a boolean checkbox for the user to check if the answer choice is correct. Since it's a checkbox, the form allows the user to select multiple answers as true unfortunately. I did it this way because I couldn't figure out how to have one radio button associated with each answer choice.

In order to force the user to mark only one answer choice as correct, i tried to create a custom validation in the Question.rb model, but this is where you'll see my horrible ruby skills. In the code below, self is the question, answers is the nested model, and correctanswer is an attribute on the nested model. I'm getting an error message

```
undefined method `correctanswer' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation
```

Can you tell me how to achieve what I'm trying to do? I'm not sure about using  `.size != 1` (i.e. will that count the number of correctanswers and reject it if it's not one?) at the end of the 'if' statement, however, since the correctanswer error popped up first, i haven't been able to see if it works.

```
validate :only_one_checked_box

  def only_one_checked_box
     if self.answers.correctanswer.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).size != 1

      self.errors[:base] << "Must mark one and only answer as correct"
    end

  end
```

Comment: why not use a radio button instead of a checkbox?  You can group those, and they only allow the user to select one option.  More here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio  The "name" attribute groups radio buttons together and only one of them can be selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm somewhat guessing here because I can't see your Answer model, but I suspect you want to do the following:

```
def only_one_checked_box
  if self.answers.select{|a| a.correctanswer == true}.size !=1
    self.errors[:base] << "Must mark one and only answer as correct"
  end
end
```

Comment: Since @kaeros likes your code, I'll accept your answer as the best answer. Both helped me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`self.answers` is an array of answers, so you should iterate and check if the answer is marked as correct. An easy way to do this is like:

```
def only_one_checked_box
  correct = 0
  self.answers.each { |a| correct += 1 if a.correctanswer }

  if correct != 1
    self.errors[:base] << "Must mark one and only answer as correct"
  end
end
```

Comment: even though you answered first and your answer helped me,  I selected boulder as the correct answer since you preferred it